# Getting "account locked" error while trying to log in Yahoo! in "Pidgin Messenger"

Tags: 12.10, pidgin, yahoo

It's been over 2 months that i get this error :

> "yahooID@yahoo.com Disabled
>
> Account locked: Too many failed login attempts.  Logging into the Yahoo! website may fix this."

I did log in to my yahoo account by going into "mail.yahoo.com" website and i could access the chats there. But still no luck with pidgin.

Before it was fine and i could sign in without a problem. And even now i can sign in via pidgin messenger with my MSN account without a problem.

I use Ubuntu 12.10.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this by going into mail.yahoo.com and use the yahoo messenger there, all i did was getting online there and then offline again, so my account was unblocked and i could access yahoo on pidgin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to yahoo.com The address mail.yahoo.com will not do this for you.  Why? I don't know.   https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Protocol%20Specific%20Questions#IgetamessagethatsaysToomanyfailedloginattemptsbutIloggedintothewebsitelikethemessagesaidanditstilldoesntwork